# Function similar to setw without calling it from iomanip library?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to avoid calling function from a certain library and my program requires the use of setw. I was wondering if I can write the function by myself, if so can someone reply with source code for setw

Comment: Look up [what `setw` does](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/). It says it just calls `width` on the stream. So you can just call `width` on the stream.

Comment: The first place to look for would be in your compiler's implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this specific function? You have to  use the library anyway, to get the stream objects.

Comment: @RSahu Compiler implementations can often obscure what the standard requirements are

Comment: As @immibis stated you can just call width directly on the stream. But as Neil stated there would seem to be little point in avoiding setw while still using the rest of the streams library. Could you post a small code example of what you are doing now and what you would like to change?

Comment: @M.M, what would be a better staring point?